# Copy subfolders and files from first level from source to destination location CMD

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a folder hierarchy like:

```
Sourcedir-
-Folder 1
--File1.xml
--File2.xml
--FolderA
---FileAA.xml
--FolderB
-Folder 2
--File3.xml
--File4.xml
--FolderC
---FileCA.xml
--FolderD
---FileDA.xml
```

I want to Copy files and Subfolders only from 1st level, to something like that:

```
DestiDir-
 -Folder 1
 --File1.xml
 --File2.xml
 -Folder 2
 --File3.xml
 --File4.xml
```

I trying to write something in cmd:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=C:\destdir" 
for /D %%A in ("%sourcedir%") do (
  for /D %%B in ("%%~fA\*") do (
   @echo xcopy /L /I "%%~fB\*.*" "%destdir%"
  )
)
```

But this one is only copying a 1st level xml files to another location i want to have also the same subfolders with this files.

Comment: add the `/E` switch to the xcop line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution useing `robocopy` mby some1 will need this info in future:

```
SET "sourcedir=C:\Test"
SET "destdir=C:\desti" 
robocopy "%sourcedir%" "%destdir%" /e /LEV:2 /XF "*.txt"
```